# Elispで変数を指定する際 'hoge と #'hoge の違いとは

Tags: elisp, lisp

`(add-hook 'hook-name 'hoge)`などで変数名がクオートのみのもの（`'hoge`）とシャープのついたもの（`#'hoge`）を見かけますが、違いは何でしょうか。
またこれはEmacs Lisp特有でしょうか。

Comment: 詳しい解説は他の方の回答のとおりですが, Emacs Lispに限っていうと byte-compile時に `#'foo`だと foo関数が定義されていなければ警告が出るというのがあります. 一方 `'foo`と書くと警告は出ません.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

まず、クオートは、(quote hoge)の略記、シャープクォートは、 (function hoge) の略記になります。
この、'hoge (quote hoge) と #'hoge (function hoge) の違いはEmacs 特有ではありません。
最初期のLISPである、LISP 1.5 から連綿と受け継がれているものです。

詳しく書くととても長くなるので、大きく2つに分けて、乱暴に箇条書きにしてしまうと、

#### Quote vs Function スコープ篇

1. 初期のLISP (1959年)で関数を引数にした場合意図しない動作となることが指摘される
2. LISP 1.5では、上記に対応するため、`function`と`funarg`を導入し、`quote`と使い分けるが、本当に実現したかったものは、Schemeのようにレキシカルスコープを持つ方式だった
3. Common Lispや最近のEmacs 24ではレキシカルスコープが利用できるようになった

等々ですが、Common Lispと最近のEmacs Lispでは、`quote`と`function`は、レキシカルスコープで書かれた場合に違いがでてきます。  
具体的には、

- クロージャーを作る(quoteだと作れない)
- ローカル関数等を作る

ですが、Emacs Lispにはローカル関数がありませんので、前者の違いのみだと思います。

#### Quote vs Function 束縛アクセスの戦略篇

なぜEmacs Lispで`quote`や`function`が殆ど同じような動作になってしまったかというと、Emacs Lispの先祖のMACLISPがクロージャーのようなものは重視せず、処理系の速度向上を図ったためです。
当時の実用的なプログラミングスタイルでは、クロージャーが多用されることは考えられておらず、そこをきちんと処理して遅くなるよりは、別の部分の速度や効率を向上させよう、という選択です。

MACLISPを先祖に持つCommon Lispではレキシカルスコープが採用されたため、クロージャーもサポートされることになるのですが、Schemeとは違い、付け足した感じは否めません。
奇しくも、Emacs Lispも後付けで、lexical-binding が導入されることとなり、Common Lispと似たような状況になっています。

### 実際のコードでの動作の違い

Emacsでの`quote`と`function`の違いですが、Emacs 24以降のlexical-binding宣言がある`lambda`の場合に動作が違ってきます。

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(fset 'ffun
      (let ((x 0))
        #'(lambda ()
            (setq x (1+ x))
            x)))

(fset 'qfun
      (let ((x 0))
        '(lambda ()
          (setq x (1+ x))
          x)))
```

をファイルに書いて、M-x load-file し、

`(qfun)`と`(ffun)`を実行してみると、qfunの方ではクロージャーが作れないことが分かります。
これは、quoteの方は単なるリストだからで、functionでなければクロージャーを作ることはできません。

### コーディングスタイル

Common Lispでは、関数は、`#'foo` と書くことが多いと思いますが、`'foo` でも間違いではありません。
`#'foo`と記述した方が効率良くコンパイルできたり、エラーが発見しやすくなることはあると思います。

`lambda`に関しては、Emacs Lisp、Common Lispともに`(lambda (x) x)`と書くと、`#'(lambda (x) x)`に展開されるマクロになっています。
Common Lispでは`lambda`には`#'`は付けないことが多いようです。また、Emacs Lispと違って`#'`の代わりに`'`を使うことはできません。

### 参考

- [function の役割り](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/doc/elisp/function.html)
- [The Influence of the Designer on the Design — J.McCarthy and LISP](https://web.archive.org/web/20061029131004/http://www8.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/html/lisp/mcc91.html)
- [クロージャ再考](http://qiita.com/pebblip/items/2ed30f59cd5981513908)

Comment: Lispってそんなに前からあったんですね...